# input returning void string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I was developing a simple form in html with javascript,but something clearly doesn't work. The problem is with the input with id = "emailregistrazione", which returns a void string "". Here the html code

```js
    const cambiaPasswordButton = document.getElementById('cambiapassword');
    const registratiButton = document.getElementById('registrati');
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const registrazioneButton = document.getElementById("registrazione");
    var emailRegistrazione = document.getElementById("emailregistrazione").value;
    var passwordRegistrazione = document.getElementById("passwordregistrazione").value;
    
    cambiaPasswordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
    });
    
    registratiButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
    });
    
    
    registrazioneButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
        console.log("il valore è"+emailRegistrazione);
    
       firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailRegistrazione, passwordRegistrazione).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            alert(emailRegistrazione)
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
          });
        });
```

```html
    <div class="container" id="container">
            <div class="form-container reimpostapassword-container">           
                <form action="#">
                    <h1>Reimposta la password</h1>
                    <span>assicurati che la nuova password sia sicura e non possa essere facilmente scoperta</span>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailrecupero"/>
                    <button>Reimposta password</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="form-container creaccount-container">
                <form action="#">
                    <h1>Creazione account</h1>
                    <span>per accedere al portale</span>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailregistrazione"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passwordregistrazione"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome Alunno">
                    <button id="registrazione">Registrati</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-container">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                        <h1>CREAZIONE ACCOUNT</h1>
                        <p>Non hai un account? Registrati ora per accedere alla piattaforma</p>
                        <button class="ghost" id="registrati">Registrati</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                        <h1>CAMBIO PASSWORD</h1>
                        <p>Hai dimenticato la password? Clicca qui sotto per impostarne una nuova</p>
                        <button class="ghost" id="cambiapassword">Cambia password</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

It could be a silly mistake, but that's my first html/js experience so I'm still learning... :)

Comment: usually, it is better if you can reduce the issue to a few lines, like 3 to 5 lines or less than 10.  It is quite often 50 lines of code is just dumped out and everybody has to debug into 50 lines of code

Comment: It is indeed a silly mistake: your defining `var email = document.getElementById('...').value` -- you're getting the value at the start of the script and never actually getting the value that the user typed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol aaand... That's a fact. Okay, thank you for your fast response. Now It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when you enter a value in the email field? It's important to note here that Placeholder != value, and will therefore not be returned by your onClick.